# JavaScript sort an array of objects by property and alphabetically

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

```js
var objs = [ 
    { status: 'Inactiv', name: 'Name_1' },
    { status: 'Extern',  name: 'Name_2' },
    { status: 'Inactiv', name: 'Name_3' },
    { status: 'Administrator', name: 'Name_3' },
    { status: 'All', name: 'Name_4' },
    { status: 'Up', name: 'Name_5' },
    { status: 'Inactiv', name: 'Name_6' },
];
```

I want to sort those items in such a way that the ones containing **"Inactiv"** to be first.
I was trying with **.sort()**, but I don't know how exactly to use the parameters.
The remaining list (without *"status: Inactiv"*) to be sort alphabetically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick

Edit: If you need the rest sorted alphabetically, you can use the code below instead

```js
var objs = [ 
    { status: 'Inactiv', name: 'Name_1' },
    { status: 'Extern',  name: 'Name_2' },
    { status: 'Inactiv', name: 'Name_3' },
    { status: 'Administrator', name: 'Name_3' },
    { status: 'All', name: 'Name_4' },
    { status: 'Up', name: 'Name_5' },
    { status: 'Inactiv', name: 'Name_6' },
];
  
 var sorted = objs.filter((obj) => obj.status == 'Inactiv').concat(objs.filter((obj) => obj.status != 'Inactiv').sort((x,y) => x.name > y.name ? 1 : -1))

console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: thanks! And if I want the remaining statuses (the ones that is not containing "Inactiv") to be also order alphabetically?

Comment: @kevx check my updated answer, I added a code for this to work

Comment: the "second" list, the ones that is not contains "Inactiv" it is not alphabetically sorted... Name_3, Name_4, Name_2, Name_5

Comment: @kevx That is a different thing entirely, I have updated it though. Check now